# Rotation of Rigid Bodies, Turning equations into Matrices

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

An excerpt from my Physics Notes. The topic is solving for angular momentum in rigid bodies.

$$\vec{r} \times (\vec{\omega}\times \vec{r})=(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r})\vec{\omega}-(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{\omega})\vec{r}$$
$$\vec{\omega}=(\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z)=\begin{bmatrix} \omega_x\\\omega_y\\ \omega_z\end{bmatrix}$$
$$(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r})\vec{\omega}-(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{\omega})\bf{\vec{r}}=\begin{bmatrix} (x^2+y^2+z^2)\omega_x\\(x^2+y^2+z^2)\omega_y\\(x^2+y^2+z^2)\omega_z\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}(x\omega_x+y\omega_y+z\omega_z) \bf{x}\\(x\omega_x+y\omega_y+z\omega_z)\bf{y}\\(x\omega_x+y\omega_y+z\omega_z)\bf{z} \end{bmatrix}$$

My question is concerning the very last $\bf{\vec{r}}$ (bolded in the work above). When it's turned into a matrix, why is it treated as$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\ z\end{bmatrix}$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix} (x+y+z)\\(x+y+z)\\(x+y+z)\end{bmatrix}$ like the $\vec{r}$ just before it, that was dotted with $\vec{\omega}$?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Check the definition of the scalar product. Your $\vec{r}$ has always been just $[x,y,z]$, not $[x+y+z, x+y+z, x+y+z]$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scalar product is defined:

\begin{equation}
\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\omega} = [x,y,z]
\left[\begin{matrix}
\omega_x\\
\omega_y\\
\omega_z
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{equation}
This construction means that you multiply each member of the row by each corresponding member of the column. That's how you get:
\begin{equation}
\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\omega} = x\omega_x+y\omega_y+z\omega_z
\end{equation}
which is a scalar, not a vector any more (that's why the operation is called *scalar* product). If now you multiply this product by $\vec{r}$ one more time you get:

\begin{equation}
(\vec{r}\cdot \vec{\omega})\vec{r} = (x\omega_x+y\omega_y+z\omega_z)
\left[\begin{matrix}
\omega_x\\
\omega_y\\
\omega_z
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{equation}
This gives you what you have obtained at the end=) Goodluck! Refresh vector calculus.

Comment: Thank you! I've never seen dot product written in matrices form and it is very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

Because the components of $\vec r$ are
$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\ y \\ z\end{array}\right),
$
not
$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x+y+z\\ x+y+z\\ x+y+z\end{array}\right)\, .
$
At no point do you use the latter incorrect expression.

$\vec r\cdot \vec \omega$ is
the scalar $x\omega_x+y\omega_y +z\omega_z$ and it's a common factor to all the components of $\vec r$.  Likewise $\vec r\cdot \vec r=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a common factor in front of $\vec \omega$.